# When to use `--no-shell-escape`?

Tags: compiling, shell-escape

I saw an introduction of `-shell-escape` here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/598819/180617

I know that if I want to use a package like `minted` or `tkz-fct`, I have to use `pdflatex --shell-escape main` to compile `main.tex`. Because they call `pygments` or `Gnuplot` **while** compiling.

In that introduction, I realized that there exists a `restrict shell escape`, *latex compiles `.tex` with this mode.

> The default setting is usually "Restricted Shell escape" this allows a small number of programs to be called by default (in a restricted form that does not allow shell redirection) these are (in a default TeX Live 2021 configuration)
>
> bibtex
>
> bibtex8
>
> extractbb
>
> gregorio
>
> kpsewhich
>
> makeindex
>
> repstopdf
>
> r-mpost
>
> texosquery-jre8

My first question is **when will `pdflatex` call something like `bibtex` or `makeindex` while compiling**? Because in my usage, I'll run `bibtex main` after `pdflatex main`, not **in** `pdflatex main`.

My second question is **when should I use `--no-shell-escape`**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `imakeidx` package for example will call `makindex` without you needing to call it explicitly.  `graphics`/`graphicx` will call `repstopdf` in the background if including EPS files, and will call `extractbb` if including PNG and other bitmap formats to get the image size.

When to turn it off is a personal choice, you may want to have a behaviour closer to the texbook, where `\write18` doesn't mean run system commands, or you may want the additional security and not trust that the commands allowed in the restricted shell escape list are in fact safe.

A lot of thought goes in to that list ensuring the programs don't allow elevated permissions, eg `repstopdf` is a custom configuration of `epstopdf` with any features allowing ghostscript to run external code disabled. So most people, most of the time, use the default restricted shell escape setting.