# texindy does not run (ubuntu 20.04, texstudio)

Tags: texstudio, ubuntu, xindy

I'm trying to run texindy on a document. I need it because I'm writing in french and makeindex doesn't understand how to sort some words with diacritics.

Unfortunately, after several tryings, I don't manage to have it run. Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[texindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

Toto\index{tata}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

I get the message :

> Processus en cours : texindy "mwe-xindy".idx
>
> ERROR: EVAL: variable BINARY has no value
>
> Processus terminé avec une ou plusieurs erreurs (= ended with one ore more errors)

I'm using TexStudio 2.12.22 under Ubuntu 20.04. I've checked the settings as you can see here :

[image]

[image]

Some things I've already tried :

- replacing `texindy %.idx` by various other things
- replacing `\usepackage[texindy]{imakeidx}` with various other options (xindy, truexindy, program=xindy, nothing, etc.)

A few other informations :

- a .idx file is created, which contains : `\indexentry{tata}{1}`, but no others (.ind, .ilg, .xdy...)
- at the end of the log file, I read this, which makes me think that there is a confusion between xindy and makeindex :

.

```
runsystem(makeindex mwe-xindy.idx)...executed safely (allowed).

(./mwe-xindy.ind) [2
```

I have checked in Synaptic (it's the software to manage the installed programs on ubuntu), and `xindy` and `xindy-rules` seem regularly installed.

Thanks in advance if you have some informations about the origin of the problem.

Comment: the setting where it says "txs:///texindy" is labeled "par défaut"; is there maybe an override that is set locally for this particular document, somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When texindy is set "par défaut" (=default), it will be running when I launch a generic "index" button, rather than makeindex, but I can also choose to run specifically texindy, and the problem is strictly the same. Something could override the generic "index" command, but note the texindy one, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with the Ubuntu package that provides `texindy` and/or with `texindy`/`xindy` itself. The file `/[relevant path]/xindy/tex/inputenc/latin.xdy` contains the following content:

```
;; Generated from latin?.xdy


Binary file (standard input) matches
```

This is clearly a mistake caused by a `grep` run on `stdin` that contained binary data instead of text. When Clisp tries to load this file it leads to the error `variable BINARY has no value` because it thinks that this line of text is Lisp code and therefore `Binary` must be a variable.

As a workaround you can let `texindy` load a different file, for example `utf8.xdy`. This also has the obvious advantage that it handles utf-8.

You can do this manually by running `texindy -C utf8 yourfile.idx` in the terminal or from within TeXstudio. It is easier however to provide this option to `\makeindex` and run LaTeX with `shell-escape`. In this case `imakeidx` runs `texindy` for you with the appropriate option.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[texindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options=-C utf8]

\begin{document}

Toto\index{tata}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/598924/ on how to enable shell escape in TeXstudio. In this case you should not press a separate button for the index, just compile the file itself and `imakeidx` will create the index.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I've solved the problem on the MWE, it was a bit more complicated on the real file because I was also using splintidex, but after a few tries it worked at the end. I don't really know what difference it makes between setting `texindy -C utf8 %.idx` in TexStudio settings, or writing \makeindex[options=-C] in the file, but it seems to work when I have both together. Thanks.