# Metapost in LaTeX (gmp package) - not working

Tags: packages, metapost

I try to use metapost code inside LaTeX, and I only receive MP Icon insted of dediecated picture:

**example of code which I want to produce:**

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\selectlanguage{polish}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[shellescape, latex]{gmp}
\gmpoptions{everymp={input expressg;}}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[top = 2.50cm, bottom = 2.50cm, left   = 2.50cm, right  = 2.50cm]{geometry}


%opening
\title{Pole wielokąta. (nr 69, str. 30)}
\author{Adam Kasprzak}

\begin{document}

%\maketitle

\section{Treść}
Dane są dwa współśrodkowe okręgi o promieniach $r=/sgrt{3}$ cm i $R=2$ cm. Pewien wielokąt jest opisany na okręgu o promieniu $r$ i jest wpisany w okrąg o promieniu $R$. Znajdź pole tego wielokąta.

\begin{figure}[htp]

    \centering

    \begin{mpost}

        z0 = origin;

        drawroundedbox(0, 2.5cm, 3cm, 5mm)();

    \end{mpost}

\end{figure}

blablabla

\end{document}
```

**allways the same result:**
[image]

Comment: updated script, please take a look again :)

Comment: Now I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKSV0.png) did you use `--shell-escape` ?

Comment: what does "use shell escape" mean? probably this is the problem O.o

Comment: I get your output if I do not use shell-escape

Comment: use `pdflatex --shell-escape file.tex` (the package warns you: `Package gmp Warning: Ensure that you have enabled the shell escape feature,`

Comment: great to know, but how to "use" this command?

Comment: I just type it on the command line, or your editor could be configured to do it for you

Comment: ok, I added it in cofigaration according to this advise: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598818/how-can-i-enable-shell-escape/598924#598924

but after this functions like "/sgrt{3}" do not works O.o do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I don't think you can leave the second argument to `drawroundedbox` empty.

Comment: `/sgrt` does not look like a regular TeX control word.  Did you mean `\sqrt` ?

Comment: you right, my mistake :p now it works perfectly, thanks to you all!

Answer (score 2):

You need

1. to run `pdflatex` with the `-shell-escape` command line option;
2. to put something inside the box, even nothing to print, but `btex...etex` is necessary.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\selectlanguage{polish}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[shellescape, latex]{gmp}
\gmpoptions{everymp={input expressg;}}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[top = 2.50cm, bottom = 2.50cm, left   = 2.50cm, right  = 2.50cm]{geometry}


%opening
\title{Pole wielokąta. (nr 69, str. 30)}
\author{Adam Kasprzak}

\begin{document}

%\maketitle

\section{Treść}
Dane są dwa współśrodkowe okręgi o promieniach $r=\sqrt{3}$ cm i $R=2$ cm. 
Pewien wielokąt jest opisany na okręgu o promieniu $r$ i jest wpisany w okrąg 
o promieniu $R$. Znajdź pole tego wielokąta.

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\begin{mpost}
z0 = origin;
drawroundedbox(0, 2.5cm, 3cm, 5mm)(btex etex);
\end{mpost}

\end{figure}

blablabla

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can do the whole of this with `lualatex` using the [`luamplib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib?lang=en) package, which is a bit more modern, and avoids mucking about with shell escape.

Here is the OP script updated for `luamplib`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\selectlanguage{polish}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\everymplib{input expressg beginfig(0);}\everyendmplib{endfig;}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[top = 2.50cm, bottom = 2.50cm, left = 2.50cm, right = 2.50cm]{geometry}
%opening
\title{Pole wielokąta. (nr 69, str. 30)}
\author{Adam Kasprzak}
\begin{document}
%\maketitle
\section{Treść}

Dane są dwa współśrodkowe okręgi o promieniach $r=\sqrt{3}$ cm i $R=2$ cm.
Pewien wielokąt jest opisany na okręgu o promieniu $r$ i jest wpisany w okrąg o
promieniu $R$. Znajdź pole tego wielokąta.

\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{mplibcode}
        z0 = origin;
        drawroundedbox(0, 2.5cm, 3cm, 5mm)("Witaj $e=mc^2$")
    \end{mplibcode}
\end{figure}

blablabla

\end{document}
```

Compile this with `lualatex` to get this:

[image]

Comment: good to know about this option, thanks!