# How to output the total numbers of all files found in same-named child folders under different-named parent folders?

Tags: structure, count

I have a project structure that looks like this:

```
1.foldername1
⌞p
  ⌞file1
  ⌞file2
2.foldername2
⌞p
  ⌞file1
  ⌞file2
3.foldername3
⌞p
  ⌞file1
  ⌞file2
```

How can I output a number total that counts every file inside a "p" folder? I don't need other details, like under which main folder it is. It should be something like:

```
Total files found in all "p" folders: X
```

Forgot to mention - I'm working on Overleaf, so I don't have access to anything else other than LaTeX (I think)

Comment: See if you can your OS to create a text document with a list of filenames.  LaTeX might be able to do something with that.

Comment: Cannot. Use a Python/Lua script. (can also shell-escape but this is "basically" bash script anyway)

Comment: Unfortunately I am on Overleaf. I'll take that as a solid "can't be done" then.

Comment: If you use overleaf then you can enable shell escape: [editors - How can I enable shell-escape? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598818/how-can-i-enable-shell-escape/598821#598821) (but that will invoke Python/Lua/whatever every time you recompile the document, which may make the compilation a bit slow)