# Issue with Loading Packages into MikTeX using a .tex file

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, miktex, shell-escape

I have uninstalled and reinstalled MikTeX along with all updates. I have loaded all packages because I have still gotten the same error after trying to load .tex file someone more experienced with LaTeX gave me.

I am using:
MikTeX and TeXworks
Windows 11.
pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX

After compiling the .tex file designed to load "needed packages", which is supposed to create a blank document at the end, I get this error:

```
auto-pst-pdf.sty
138
Package auto-pst-pdf Error: 
    "shell escape" (or "write18") is not enabled:
    auto-pst-pdf will not work!
.

See the auto-pst-pdf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.138         Or turn off auto-pst-pdf.}
                                        %
```

Following is what shows up in the compiler:

```
Package ifplatform Warning: 
    shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.

)

! Package auto-pst-pdf Error: 
    "shell escape" (or "write18") is not enabled:
    auto-pst-pdf will not work!
.

See the auto-pst-pdf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.138         Or turn off auto-pst-pdf.}
```

I have researched this thoroughly on stackexchange and other resources. I have spent about 16 hours on this in total.

I have attempted to manually turn on write18 and shell escape using the preferences for pdfLaTeX. i have ensured that I used the correct syntax. I have run a tex file to see if it is enabled. It is not. I have also tried to update a PDF file per other instructions I was provided. I have referenced the recommended documents to no avail.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: auto-pst-pdf is rather complicated, not always compatible with a current latex and one can't debug it without a small, complete example that demonstrate the problem. Are you sure that you need auto-pst-pdf?

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. This is a technical manual we created. It was fully compiled using the code I have. The resource I had doing this left the company. i had to make some edits to the reference files and am trying to recompile it. I do not know if I need auto-pst-pdf. I am trying to disrupt the code as minimally as possible.

Comment: well at first check that you know how to enable shell-escape. Compile this and tell which number it prints `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\the\pdfshellescape
\end{document}`

Comment: Thank you. The result is 2.

Comment: that's wrong, you need 1. Compile on a command line with `pdflatex --shell-escape test`  (where test.tex is the document).

Comment: Thank you. Where do I need to store the document? I have it on my desktop. It cannot find the document.

Comment: @JonathanThomas see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598818/how-can-i-enable-shell-escape, maybe your editor is listed there so you don't need to use the command line (even though it would be a good idea to learn how to use that anyway for many other purposes).