# ! LaTeX Error: File `main-words.sum' not found

Tags: errors

I use a template from school incluing five parts——main.tex, main.pdf, sample.bib, UCLISH.cls, Figures folder. I want to run the main.tex, but there is an error showing `` ! LaTeX Error: File `main-words.sum' not found. `` I looked into the UCLISH.cls and found there is a string of codes:

```
\newcommand{\quickwordcount}[1]{%
  \immediate\write18{texcount -sum=1 -q -1 -merge  #1.tex > #1-words.sum }%
  \input{#1-words.sum}%
}
```

Maybe these codes are related to this problem. But I do not know how to deal with it. Do I need to download any packages？

[image: maim.tex]
[image: total file]
[image: UCLISH.cls]

Comment: write18 requires `pdflatex --shell-escape` to allow system commands.

Comment: Addendum to David's comment: [How can I enable shell-escape?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/598818/277964)