# create letter charts with pictures for children - for alphabet learning

Tags: graphics, charts

I want to produce something like this below, but with just one letter chart per (A4) page, to make it suitable for printing and hanging up on the wall. How this could be done?

Let's assume I already have the images.

[image: alphabet chart]

Thanks!

Comment: If you already have the images, what it the problem? Do you not know, how to include full size images (using `pdfpages`)? Do you not know, how to overprint images by text? Do you not know, how to scale image (using `graphicx`)? Can you please show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) of what you already have and explain your problem?

Comment: If the problem is creating letters **much** larger than `\huge`, use `\scalebox` or `\adjustbox` (graphicx and adjustbox packages).

Answer (score 4):

Your question is quite unclear, because you did not specify what exactly you are failing at. Here is an example, where the whole image from your question is divided into single A4 pages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{shellesc}
\IfFileExists{ukUUd.png}{}{%
  \ifnum \ShellEscapeStatus=1
    \ShellEscape{wget https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukUUd.png}%
  \else
    \errmessage{Shell escape must be enabled. Please run again with option --shell-escape}%
  \fi
}

\newcount\ROW
\newcount\COLUMN
\newlength{\XLEFT}
\newlength{\XRIGHT}
\newlength{\YBOTTOM}
\newlength{\YTOP}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\@whilenum\ROW<4 \do{%
  \COLUMN=0
  \YTOP=\dimexpr 161px*\ROW+17px\relax
  \YBOTTOM=\dimexpr 161px*\numexpr (3-\ROW)\relax+12px\relax
  \@whilenum\COLUMN<8 \do{%
    \XLEFT=\dimexpr 125px*\COLUMN+12px\relax
    \XRIGHT=\dimexpr 125px*\numexpr(7-\COLUMN)\relax+11px\relax
    \advance\COLUMN by 1
    \edef\CMD{\noexpand\includepdf
      [trim=\the\XLEFT\space \the\YBOTTOM\space\the\XRIGHT\space \the\YTOP,clip,width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]
      {uKUUd.png}}%
    \show\CMD
    \CMD
  }%
  \advance\ROW by 1  
}%
\end{document}
```

You need to [enable shell-escape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/598818/277964) to compile the example. As an alternative download https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukUUd.png manually and put it into the same directory as the document.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

[image]

The code works with pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, and LuaLaTeX. The table is set up in landscape mode, with four rows and 8 equal-width columns. It's assumed that the image files for the 4 by 8 table are named `image11`, `image12`, thru `image48`. A macro called `\DoCell`, which takes three arguments, does the job for each of the 4 x 8 = 32 cells.

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
\else
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setsansfont{Myriad Pro} % choose a suitable sans-serif font
\fi

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X}

\usepackage{graphicx} % for \includgraphics macro
\usepackage{rotating} % for \sidewaystable env.

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
% make suitable choices for "red" and "blue"
\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\usepackage{colortbl} % for \arrayrulecolor macro

\newcommand\DoCell[3]{%
    {\Huge #1\enspace\MakeLowercase{#1}\strut} 
  
    %\vspace{1pt}
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth,
                     height=1.9cm, % set height appropriately
                     keepaspectratio]{#2}
  
    \Large #3\strut%
}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault

\begin{sidewaystable}

\setlength\extrarowheight{14pt}
\arrayrulecolor{gray}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{8}{C|}}
\hline
% Cell 1,1
\DoCell{A}{image11}{\red{A}RBUZ}
&
% Cell 1,2
\DoCell{Ą}{image12}{W\red{Ą}Ż}
&
 
&
 
&
 
&
 
&
 
&

\\
\hline
%Cell 2,1
\DoCell{F}{image21}{\blue{F}ARB}
&
 
&
 
&
 
&
 
&
 
&
 
&
%Cell 2,8
\DoCell{Ł}{image28}{\blue{Ł}YŻKA}
\\
\hline
%Cell 3,1
\DoCell{M}{image31}{\blue{M}ALINA}
&
 
&
 
&
 
&
 
&
 
&
 
&

\\
\hline
%Cell 4,1
\DoCell{Ś}{image41}{\blue{Ś}LIMAK}
&
 %Cell 4,2
\DoCell{T}{image42}{\blue{T}ORT}
&
 
&
 
&
 
&
 
&
 
&
%Cell 4,8
\DoCell{Ż}{image48}{\blue{Ż}ABA}
\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```