# LuaTex, Xelatex with VimTex

Tags: xetex, luatex, vim

I'm trying to use Georgian language with vimtex. I found out that I have to compile with XelaTex or LuaTex but i don't know how to make vimtex to compile with them. I would like to keep default compiler and add Xelatex as optional, is it possible? I have tried to read official documentation but I can't understand much.

Comment: Can you just use the Vim command line?   `:!lualatex %` should do it.

Comment: Add `%!TeX program = xelatex` as the first line of your file... then close and reopen it. Anyway, this question is probably better suited for the vi/vim site.

Comment: :!lualatex % in principle works. I have some errors but i might fix them.

Comment: %!TeX program = xelatex worked as well. Thanks for solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without touching the default, you can use, in `vimtex`, the "magic comment" `TeX program`:

```latex
%! TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\begin{document}
I have been compiled with\dots{\ttfamily
\ifluatex
    luatex
\else\ifxetex
    xetex
\else\ifpdftex
    pdftex
\else
    NO IDEA!
\fi\fi\fi}

\end{document}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Notice a couple of things:

1. if you change the "magic comment", you have to *reload the plugin* to acknowledge it (the standard keystrokes are `\lx`, if you didn't change the leader char).
2. the `xelatex` there is *not* a program name; it's a label for a set of configurations defined elsewhere. The most common ones are `xelatex` and `lualatex`. Using a generic command here can hinder all the security things that makes `--shell-escape` needed.
3. there is much more info directly in `vim` if you execute `:h vimtex-tex-directives`:

```
SUPPORT FOR TEX DIRECTIVES                              *vimtex-tex-directives*

VimTeX supports two of the commonly used TeX directives [0]: the TeX root and
the TeX program directive. The TeX root directive was already described above,
see |vimtex-tex-root|.

                                                           *vimtex-tex-program*
The TeX program directive works by specifying the TeX compiler program in
a comment in one of the first lines of the main project file. It is parsed
only when it is required by a compiler backend.

The syntax is best explained with an example: >latex

  %! TeX program = lualatex
  %! TEX TS-program = xelatex

The left-hand side must contain the text "tex program" or "tex ts-program" and
as with |vimtex-tex-root|, the words are recognized regardless of casing and
the spaces are ignored. The right-hand side must correspond to a key in the
|g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk_engines| or |g:vimtex_compiler_latexrun_engines|
dictionaries. See also [0,1].
```

0: [When and why should I use % !TEX TS-program and % !TEX encoding?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78101/34697)

1: https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/713

Not directly related, but you probably can also be interested in this: [How can I enable shell-escape?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598818/how-can-i-enable-shell-escape)

Comment: Thank you very much.