# How to insert a eps file

Tags: shell-escape, epstopdf

I have a .EPs file I need to include in my latex document.
A previous answer suggested epstopdf. Also how can I incorporate  shell-escapae into my preamble.

Comment: Up-to-date TeX distributions automatically use restricted epstopdf to convert EPS to PDF if needed (e.g. using PDFLaTeX or LuaLaTeX). This usually does not need to explicitly activate shell-escape. However, if the automatic conversion does not work, you can load [package `epstopdf`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf-pkg). You also [can activate shell-escape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/598818/277964) if really needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{filename.eps}
```